# Add a file to iOS application after install it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have an iOS project that includes a framework and a `.dat` file which is used by framework. I add the framework file and the `.dat` file to a folder in my project and things are working in this way.

However, the .dat file is so big and this makes my project size bigger. I want to download this file after installation to make my app size smaller.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: you can download it at very first launch of app after installation. But there are many scenarios to take care of.

Comment: I think I asked my question to Google in a wrong way, I couldn't find any related solution. Can you give an example or way to do that?

Comment: do you just wanna download .dat file?

Comment: Yes, download and use in my app. Right now I add this .dat file to my project directly.

Comment: I think you can save .dat file on anywhere(server, cloud ...). And you add Url download of it on your app. When app after install on device of user and launch first time, you can download file this here

Answer (score 2):

Check this [On-Demand Resources]

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH2-SW1

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store .dat file on server and get link of that file and download it in app at very first launch.

- When app is launched you need to check that .dat file is already exists in your device's doc. folder or not.
- If not then you need to download it from url and store it in doc. dir.
- When you successfully downloaded file you need to add a bool in user default to true to identify that file is dowloaded correctly, and you can check that too to identify whether file is downloaded or not.
- if .dat file download is not successful than file will not be available in app. and you can perform some operations based on that.
- Alternatively, you can just check the bool flag in user defaults to check for the successful download of file.
- you can place that code in `AppDelegate` as there are several methods available for different app states.

Hope it will help you:)